# Error 11001 when running SMTP with Anaconda 3 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

**On Udemy, the instructor is showing us how to use SMTP. I am using Jupyter Notebook (I know it's just to learn the basics then I am going to switch over to an IDE) and Anaconda (Python). When I run this I get these errors. (This happens with no port numbers, and the 2 port numbers our teacher told us 587,465. I also turned off windows firewall when doing this because that might have been interfering but it still didn't work.
Port Number 465**

````
```smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com',465)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cf67d6421353> in <module>
----> 1 smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com',465)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    249 
    250         if host:
--> 251             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    252             if code != 220:
    253                 self.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    334         if self.debuglevel > 0:
    335             self._print_debug('connect:', (host, port))
--> 336         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    337         self.file = None
    338         (code, msg) = self.getreply()
    enter code here

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
    305             self._print_debug('connect: to', (host, port), self.source_address)
    306         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
--> 307                                         self.source_address)
    308 
    309     def connect(self, host='localhost', port=0, source_address=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    705     host, port = address
    706     err = None
--> 707     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    708         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    709         sock = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    750     # and socket type values to enum constants.
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    754         addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed```
````

**Port number 587**

````
```smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com',587)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-40083b789b9c> in <module>
----> 1 smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com',587)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    249 
    250         if host:
--> 251             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    252             if code != 220:
    253                 self.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    334         if self.debuglevel > 0:
    335             self._print_debug('connect:', (host, port))
--> 336         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    337         self.file = None
    338         (code, msg) = self.getreply()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
    305             self._print_debug('connect: to', (host, port), self.source_address)
    306         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
--> 307                                         self.source_address)
    308 
    309     def connect(self, host='localhost', port=0, source_address=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    705     host, port = address
    706     err = None
--> 707     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    708         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    709         sock = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    750     # and socket type values to enum constants.
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    754         addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed```
````

**No Port Number**

````
```smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1655d3855dcf> in <module>
----> 1 smtp_object = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gamil.com')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    249 
    250         if host:
--> 251             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    252             if code != 220:
    253                 self.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    334         if self.debuglevel > 0:
    335             self._print_debug('connect:', (host, port))
--> 336         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    337         self.file = None
    338         (code, msg) = self.getreply()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
    305             self._print_debug('connect: to', (host, port), self.source_address)
    306         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
--> 307                                         self.source_address)
    308 
    309     def connect(self, host='localhost', port=0, source_address=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    705     host, port = address
    706     err = None
--> 707     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    708         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    709         sock = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    750     # and socket type values to enum constants.
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    754         addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed```
````

Comment: What is "gamil.com"? Is it meant to be Gmail?

Comment: Your right I am dumb, my bad.